# 404 redirect - htaccess problems with subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've set a redirect 404 that is working fine for home directly but it does not work for subdomain. What I want no matter where the error comes it should direct to my main domain www.domain.com below is my .httaccess file please advise

Comment: You have some code we can see?

Comment: here's the code

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/

Comment: It's working only for main domain not for subdomains such as if someone writes abc.mydomain.com, it just give general browser error instead of redirecting to the home page.

Comment: is your sub domain are setup in a different folder than the www domain?

Comment: my subdomains are inside main folder public_html/domain, subdomain folders n main domains files all are here

Comment: maybe you have other rules that overwrites the main one?

Comment: No, actually I used to have subdomains now they are removed that's why I need a redirect that anyone try to open subdomain must be directed to main page. Any idea what should be done at htaccess file or any other alternative?

Comment: can you update your question and put all the details on your domain and subdomains? that will help me

Comment: Ok alright I think I'll need little help from you in tweaking below htaccess code n my problem will be solved.

this code will do like this. If i try to access domain.com/dir then this code will transfer it to dir.domain.com. Below is the code

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.domain.com [R=301,NC,L]

What I want is, to  do some tweaking that you type subdomain.com the code should bring it to domain.com/subdomain. Hope you get my question now

Comment: so you want to go from a sub-domain to a domain.com/subfolder eg: sub.domain.com => domain.com/sub

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

put that in your .htaccess on your root folder. This will redirect sub.domain.com => domain.com/sub

Comment: I tried but it's returning dir.domain.com again to same address dir.domain.com, there's only one code in htaccess so no conflict or overriding possible.

Comment: have you tried to clear cache? you don'T have .htaccess in that folder? this folder use the .htaccess from the root folder?

Comment: Yes, i've cleared cache n put .htaccess in the root directory it does return dir.domain.com redirecting to the same dir.domain.com

Comment: can you give me the folder structure (where dir. goes and www goes)?

Comment: actually when dir.domain.com redirects to domain.com/dir then i've this to direct it to main site ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/ now the problem is at first step ur code is not redirectly as desired

Comment: did you try: `ErrorDocument 404 /`. I updated my answer with MY config which I use for languages (en.domain.com) and en.domain.com works, if I put zz.domain.com it goes to domain.com

Comment: yes, it works but only brings to homepage if url pattern is domain.com/abc or domain.com/abc.html etc but it does not redirect if ulr pattern is abc.domain.com

Comment: then your subdomain does not read the .htaccess correctly. maybe you can create symblink or check your folder stucture

Comment: ok I'll try to do that too, thanks anyway for trying to help me! :)